# Android resource compilation failed (unescaped character) - even though I fixed the error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

My strings.xml file used to include an unescaped apostrophe:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My second app</string>
    <string name="title">I'm here!!!</string>
</resources>
```

Then when I built the app, it broke. So I fixed it:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My second app</string>
    <string name="title">I&apos;m here!!!</string>
</resources>
```

And saved, but it's still breaking with the same error:

```
C:\Users\O\Downloads\intro_android_demo-master\Mysecondapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:381: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
"I'm here!!!".
```

Is this normal in Android studio? Is this a bug? Or what did I miss? My Android studio version is 3.4.2

Comment: do a clean and rebuild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\'`.

In your example:

```
<string name="title">I\'m here!!!</string>
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele it solved it. I don't understand why the apostrophe special character didn't work though.

Comment: You can also enclose the entire string in double quotes: `"I'm here!!!"`